# Code was skipped after a instance of JPanel was created

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jpanel, awt

I am making a copy of the game Tetris and have created a game panel.

I was trying to swap the order of `tetris.initGamePanel();` and `tetris.initWindow();` in

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        Tetris tetris = new Tetris();
        tetris.initGamePanel();
        tetris.initWindow();//Why the order matters???
        //tetris.initGamePanel();
    }
```

and found out that when `tetris.initGamePanel();` was excuted first the program ran perfectly well but a blank window appeared when the order was changed to the other way round.

So i tried to debug the coden and found that the rest of the code in

```
public void initGamePanel(){
        JPanel game_main = new JPanel();
        game_main.setLayout(new GridLayout(game_x,game_y,1,1));
        //initialize game panel

        for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < text[i].length; j++){
                //create a new JTextArea Object that contains parameter i and j
                text [i][j] = new JTextArea();
                text [i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                text [i][j].addKeyListener(this);
                text [i][j].setEditable(false);


                if(j == 0 || j == text[i].length-1 || i == text.length-1 ){
                    text [i][j].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    data [i][j] = 1;
                }
                game_main.add(text[i][j]);

            }

        }
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(game_main,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

was skipped after the JPanel instance was created in

```
public void initGamePanel(){
        JPanel game_main = new JPanel();
```

But the strange thing is, everything seemed working well(in the correct order) dispite the fact that the rest of the code wasn't even gone through.

This is the whole piece of the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Tetris extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    private static final int game_x = 24;
    private static final int game_y = 12;
    public Tetris(){
        text = new JTextArea[game_x][game_y];
        data = new int[game_x][game_y];
        //initGamePanel();
    }

    JTextArea[][] text;
    int [][] data;

    public void initWindow(){
        this.setSize(400,800);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//align to the center if the component is set to null

        this.setVisible(true);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setResizable(false);

        this.setTitle("Tetris");
    }

    public void initGamePanel(){
        JPanel game_main = new JPanel();
        game_main.setLayout(new GridLayout(game_x,game_y,1,1));
        //initialize game panel

        for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < text[i].length; j++){
                //create a new JTextArea Object that contains parameter i and j
                text [i][j] = new JTextArea();
                text [i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                text [i][j].addKeyListener(this);
                text [i][j].setEditable(false);


                if(j == 0 || j == text[i].length-1 || i == text.length-1 ){
                    text [i][j].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    data [i][j] = 1;
                }
                game_main.add(text[i][j]);

            }

        }
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(game_main,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tetris tetris = new Tetris();
        tetris.initGamePanel();
        tetris.initWindow();//Why the order matters???
        //tetris.initGamePanel();
    }

}
```

I assume it's because JPanel's constructor somehow went through the rest of the code, but how?

Comment: Code isn't magic. It's all executed in the order you wrote it. So if your debugging found that "the rest of the code was skipped", you must have missed something. Either an exception was thrown, or the code continued running. There are no magic skips.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I double-checked the debugging process, the code was indeed still running after I went through it. But why does the order of calling the two methods I mentioned above matter? Is it because "initWindow()" is dependent on "initGamePanel()" so that the order can't be changed?

Comment: Swing is lazy.  Calculating the layout and repainting the UI are expensive operations, so rather then trying to update the UI every time you add or remove components, the API requires YOU to request a new layout/paint pass when you think it's suitable.  Add a call to `revalidate` and `repaint` to the end of your `initGamePanel` call.

Answer (score 2):

`initGamePanel` is updating the UI.  If called before `initWindow`, the UI's layout is calculated and will get painted as part of the windows process of becoming visible.

If you reverse the calls, nothing is telling the system that the state of the UI has changed, and therefore it won't perform those operations.

Swing is lazy.  When you change the state of the UI (especially the layout (ie adding/removing components)), YOU must inform the system that a new layout and paint pass should be performed.

You should add a call to `revalidate` and `repaint` at the end of the `initGamePanel` method, for example...

```
public void initGamePanel(){
    // ...
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

`this.setSize(400,800);` is a bad idea.  A windows viewable content will be the size of the window MINUS the window decorations insets.

Instead, you should make use of the layout management system and instead call `pack` on the window (but you should really only do that AFTER you've established the base layout).

I would also change `text [i][j] = new JTextArea();` to something like `text [i][j] = new JTextArea(1, 1);` so as to allow the `JTextArea` to report a suitable preferred size.  Not sure why you're using `JTextArea` of this, seems overly complicated for the task, but that's me.

`text [i][j].addKeyListener(this);` is also a poor choice for monitoring keyboard input.  I might consider a `DocumentListener` instead or, if you're not using text input components, make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, this will save you from a lot of seemingly random issues.

There was an issue with calling `this.setResizable(false);` AFTER a window was made visible which changed the size of the window decorations and did all sorts of weird things.  As a user, I'd be grateful if you didn't do this, but instead, make extensive use of the layout management API to better manage the components when the window is resized.

Also, the work done by `initGamePanel` should really be done in the constructor, that way the UI is prepared by the time the constructor returns.

You should also avoid extending from top level containers such as `JFrame`. You're not adding a new functionality to the class and are locking yourself into a single use context.  `JFrame` is also a complex, compound component, usually best to avoid that mess if you can.